# Why the String argument of the event is been replaced by a mouseEvent?

Tags: angular, eventemitter

I'm trying to send an image src from a child to the parent through an event emmiter, I got it, but 
    immediately the string is replaced by the mouseEvent object.
    Why this is happening, what can I do to stop this to happen?
    Thanks!

Angular 5

html-parent:

```
<!-- language: HTML -->

<vcard-event name="Expo" place="Hotel California" 
(click)='viewImage($event);$event.preventDefault(); 
$event.stopPropagation();'></vcard-event>



ts-parent:
<!-- language: TypeScript -->

viewImage(src: String){
    this.srcImage = src;
    this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
    console.log("SRC: ",this.srcImage);
}
```

It returns:

> SRC:  ../../assets/imgs/journey.png

but then I get:

> $event.preventDefault is not a function...

and finally:

> SRC: MouseEvent{isTrusted...}
>   event.prevent... is not a functions

It doesn't happen if I remove
    ";$event.preventDefault(); $event.stopPropagation();",

But the other  two lines still remain there.

html-child:

```
<!-- language: HTML -->
<button  class="bigButton" (click)="viewImage()"> View Image</button>
```

ts- child:

```
<!-- language: TypeScript -->
@Output() click: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

viewImage(){
    this.click.emit("../../assets/imgs/journey.png");
}
```

It should show:

> SRC:  ../../assets/imgs/journey.png

and stop there, not replace it with MouseEvent object.

Answer (score 0):

click is already a defined output in angular, you should change the name of your EventEmitter to something different.

```
@Output() imageClick: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

 viewImage(){
   this.imageClick.emit("../../assets/imgs/journey.png");
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried but with this change I don't even get the src ("../../assets/imgs/journey.png"), only the MouseEvent object

Comment: you probably didn't update the html in the parent `<vcard-event name="Expo" place="Hotel California" 
(clicker)='viewImage(link)... `